# ServiceStack.DataAnnotations missing attributes definitions?

Tags: c#, attributes, servicestack

I'm trying to use ServiceStack's attribute decorators from ServiceStack.DataAnnotations but when I view the ServiceStack.DataAnnotations namespace in the MSVS Object Browser, there are only the following types:

ComputeAttribute
DecimalLengthAttribute
IgnoreAttribute
PrimaryKeyAttribute

I have the latest bins and all of my references check out.  Specifically, I'm looking to use the [AutoIncrement] and [Index] attribs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AutoIncrement] and [Index] attributes are in the [ServiceStack.Interfaces.DataAnnotations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/DataAnnotations) namespace in the dependency-free **ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll** which if you're using NuGet you can find inside the [ServiceStack.Common NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common).

Comment: Is there a reason why for example PrimaryKey is placed in ServiceStack.DataAnnotations and the other attributes (Index etc) is placed in another DLL? Why not have all of them in the same place? any idea?

Comment: @Ted In **v4** all OrmLite attributes are available in [ServiceStack.Interfaces](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/DataAnnotations).