# Is it possible NOT to use data annotations attributes ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: data-annotations, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to explore the functionality of ServiceStack.OrmLite and can't understand if it possible to use bootstrap class for configuration (foreign keys, data types, column indexes, aliases etc.)? I don't wanna use data annotation attributes on my entity classes. Even usage of some sort of config's would be better than attributes. That is because i wanna have the chance to replace the ORM in future. Maybe exists third-party lib for fluent configuration?

Answer (score 7):

There is no fluent mapping for ServiceStack.OrmLite. I share your reluctance to refer even the DataAnnotations assembly from my Model definitions. I like my POCO's clean as in entirely clean: separate in their own assembly, not referencing any 3rd party assemblies. It's not as much aesthetics as it's a ways of twisting my arm to avoid temptations to do short-hand stuff that breaks good design. I'm like - if it's not a clean ORM, it's just a tightly coupled DAL, and then it's all for nothing anyway.

Anyway - you can definately annotate your POCO classes in a bootstrapping/impl. kind of place - it's really quite obvious: use reflection and add the attribute at runtime, e.g.

```cs
typeof (User).GetProperty("Id")
    .AddAttributes(new AutoIncrementAttribute());
```

Same principle of any attribute of OrmLite (and any attribute, really).

I found the hint in the Unit-tests for OrmLite, there's actually a `Can_add_AutoIncrement_Id_at_runtime()` unit test. Even though this is essentially unit-testing .NET core and not really OrmLite. Thanks, thourough tester-guy, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[ServiceStack OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/) creates schemas based on code-first POCOs. Adding attributes are a convenience to alter the sql generated table schema if you wanted OrmLite to create the tables for you. If you don't want to use attributes then manually create the SQL Schema in your database out-of-band, or after the tables are created remove the attributes.

Or use another ORM, OrmLite will never support mappings stored in runtime configuration files - which is against it's code-first philosophy.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to me that i begin to realize the main concept of ServiceStack OrmLite. But wouldn't it be nice to have a fluent API (like NHibernate or EF does) to help configure SQL schema? As i see there is no configuration API for this ORM and it was not planned ever.

Comment: There's no value in it, there's nothing preventing re-use of attributed POCO's as they're benign for fx's that don't make use of it. Likewise you could remove project-wide attributes with just a few regexes. All that bloat + effort to implement a separate configuration source doesn't actually create extra value, it would just be to appease some developer aesthetic preferences - which is not a great strategy if your goal was to keep a clean and lean code-base.

Comment: I can't entirely agree on the last statement because if one places models to a separate assembly, then orm assembly must be referenced and needed to be deployed alongside with it. But nevertheless i appreciate your arguments about clean and lean code-base.

Comment: Most of the attributes are kept in [ServiceStack.Interfaces.DataAnnotations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/DataAnnotations) which is an impl-free assembly with no dependencies (i.e. the min dep possible in .NET). The goal is to move all OrmLite attributes so models wouldn't need a dependency on OrmLite.

Comment: Hi @mythz , i tried to remove the [Ignore] from my POCOs after creating my tables in the database, but when i try to insert an object that contains a property that no more had the ignore attribute, it throws an sql exception. Does that mean that i can't get rid of the attributes even after creating the database ?

Comment: @YAT if you remove the `[Ignore]`, than that property is assumed to be apart of the schema (the class definition is the master schema) and participate in future SQL operations as if that column existed. Only public properties map to db columns, so if you don't want to use `[Ignore]` you can use a public field or method instead.

Comment: @mythz also answered my question, and in v4 it seems that attributes isnt required anymore:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378284/servicestack-dataannotations-missing-attributes-definitions